# How do I get a dataframe to write all data pulled to csv and not skip any rows with missing data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, yfinance

The following is working great for hundreds of stocks.  But some stocks have incomplete data.  E.g., blank `shortRatio` amount, etc.  When that happens, it skips the entire row instead of just leaving certain fields blank.  For example, out of `symbols = ['AI', 'AG', 'MA']`, only `'MA'` outputs any data.  How do I get it to write to csv whatever data is available and not skip rows just because one field is blank?

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker
import csv

symbols = ['AI', 'AG', 'MA']

modules = 'financialData defaultKeyStatistics price summaryDetail earningsTrend'

for tick in symbols:
    tickers = Ticker(tick)
    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame([{'symbol': ticker,
'financialCurrency': data['financialData']['financialCurrency'], 
'shortRatio': data['defaultKeyStatistics']['shortRatio'], 
'shortPercentOfFloat': data['defaultKeyStatistics']['shortPercentOfFloat'], 
'priceToBook': data['defaultKeyStatistics']['priceToBook'], 
'earningsQuarterlyGrowth': data['defaultKeyStatistics']['earningsQuarterlyGrowth'], 
'marketCap': data['price']['marketCap'], 
'shortName': data['price']['shortName'], 
'fiftyTwoWeekLow': data['summaryDetail']['fiftyTwoWeekLow'], 
'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': data['summaryDetail']['fiftyTwoWeekHigh'], 
        'growth': data['earningsTrend']['trend'][-1]['growth']}                     
                           for ticker, data in tickers.get_modules(modules).items()])
    except Exception:
        continue
    try:
        df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=False)
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        continue
```

Comment: `except Exception: continue` is a terrible construct if you want to know what's happening. You're catching almost everything and just sweeping it under the rug. _At the very least_ you'd want `exception Exception as e: print(e)` so you could see what's happening with some rows.

Comment: What about trying to change the value of `NaN` to `0` or `No Data` with `df = df.fillna([insert your value here])`?

Comment: Hi @roganjosh, Okay, I can change it.  I was using `except (KeyError, TypeError)`, but just changed it temporarily.  Sorry for the mix up, but it still is not writing the rows I need regardless of the exception used.

Comment: The point of the change, though, is - do you now see anything being printed out? `except (KeyError, TypeError)` still swallows the error if you choose not to print something when it actually happens. You could even go one step further and use [`traceback.format_exc()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc) but the point is that the exception isn't just silently passed over. It's not clear to me atm why rows get skipped at all, and I can't determine whether it's a client-side or server-side decision to omit them

Comment: Thank you @roganjosh.  I edited the exception and here is what it printed out: `'earningsQuarterlyGrowth'
'shortPercentOfFloat'`

Comment: Thank you, @Marcelo Paco.  I have added `df = df.fillna(['NoData'])` before this line: `df = pd.DataFrame([{'symbol': ticker,` , but it is still not pulling any data.  I tried putting `df = df.fillna(['NoData'])` elsewhere as well, but so far nothing.

Comment: In which case you'll probably need to use the `traceback` mechanism I posted in my last message because that isn't an error in itself. You're probably getting a `KeyError` in the payload but I can't be sure

Comment: @roganjosh, it is not a server-side decision yahooquery pulls from yahoo finance api.  If I omit `'earningsQuarterlyGrowth'` and `'shortPercentOfFloat'`, it will pull the data for all rows without issue.

Comment: So much for RESTful, then, because it would seem that if the data doesn't exist then the payload doesn't include the key. It's still speculation because you haven't showed me the error, but I'm not sure what else it could be at this point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252591/discussion-between-htmlhelpme-and-roganjosh).

Comment: @roganjosh 
I don't know how to use traceback. I put traceback.format_exc() in the code, but got back NameError: name 'traceback' is not defined.  I'm not sure what error you're looking for.

Comment: You need to import traceback, just like any other method. Then you need `print(traceback.format_exc`

Comment: @roganjosh Okay, thanks.  Here's the result `<function format_exc at 0x00000...0>`

Comment: I typo'd. `print(format_exc())`. You just got the function memory address

Comment: @roganjosh `NoneType: None`, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does what you expect:

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker
import csv

symbols = ['AI', 'AG', 'MA']

modules = 'financialData defaultKeyStatistics price summaryDetail earningsTrend'

with open('output.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['symbol', 'financialCurrency', 'shortRatio', 'shortPercentOfFloat', 
                     'priceToBook', 'earningsQuarterlyGrowth', 'marketCap', 'shortName', 
                     'fiftyTwoWeekLow', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh', 'growth'])

    for tick in symbols:
        tickers = Ticker(tick)
        try:
            data = tickers.get_modules(modules)
            data_dict = {'symbol': tick}
            financial_data = data.get(tick, {}).get('financialData', {})
            data_dict['financialCurrency'] = financial_data.get('financialCurrency', '')
            default_statistics = data.get(tick, {}).get('defaultKeyStatistics', {})
            data_dict['shortRatio'] = default_statistics.get('shortRatio', '')
            data_dict['shortPercentOfFloat'] = default_statistics.get('shortPercentOfFloat', '')
            data_dict['priceToBook'] = default_statistics.get('priceToBook', '')
            data_dict['earningsQuarterlyGrowth'] = default_statistics.get('earningsQuarterlyGrowth', '')
            price_data = data.get(tick, {}).get('price', {})
            data_dict['marketCap'] = price_data.get('marketCap', '')
            data_dict['shortName'] = price_data.get('shortName', '')
            summary_data = data.get(tick, {}).get('summaryDetail', {})
            data_dict['fiftyTwoWeekLow'] = summary_data.get('fiftyTwoWeekLow', '')
            data_dict['fiftyTwoWeekHigh'] = summary_data.get('fiftyTwoWeekHigh', '')
            earnings_trend = data.get(tick, {}).get('earningsTrend', {})
            data_dict['growth'] = earnings_trend.get('trend', [])[-1].get('growth', '')
            writer.writerow(data_dict.values())
        except KeyError:
            continue
```

Now, if you open the `ouput.csv` file:

```
df=pd.read_csv('output.csv')
```

you will get:

```
  symbol financialCurrency  shortRatio  shortPercentOfFloat  priceToBook  \
0     AI               USD        0.71               0.2460     2.556160   
1     AG               USD        2.24                  NaN     1.413673   
2     MA               USD        2.13               0.0062    53.075290   

   earningsQuarterlyGrowth     marketCap                    shortName  \
0                      NaN    2476463104                  C3.ai, Inc.   
1                      NaN    1995270912  First Majestic Silver Corp.   
2                    0.061  331728388096      Mastercard Incorporated   

   fiftyTwoWeekLow  fiftyTwoWeekHigh    growth  
0            10.16             30.92        {}  
1             5.85             14.59  -0.33077  
2           276.87            390.00   0.12854
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Serge de Gosson de Varennes.  This works great!